# References on blowing up algebraic stacks.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-stacks

The title says the question. I want to know if there are any texts about blowing up for stacks, including definition and necessary purity checks.

Comment: Not really my area but section 2 of the Compositio paper "Functorial destackification of tame stacks with abelian stabilisers" by Bergh seems like a good place to start looking.